# why do the source code located on app/resources/tmp/cache folder ?

Tags: php, lithium

I'm new in lithium. I have a lithium codes, and i want to change it a bit. so, my idea was to search in the all source code for specific code that i want to change (e.g.  tag>), and i found it in the app/resources/tmp/cache subfolder. why do the source code located there?

Comment: Sounds like it's cached code, which would be a sign of generated code. Don't edit generated code, that won't play well in the long run ;) Edit the configuration for generating the code instead. But I can't tell you where that is for lithium.

Answer (score 3):

Lithium generates cached php files for the views (templates). These files have mixed html and php code. You can see in the file name which view this is: `template_views_<folder_of_the_view>_<action_of_the_view>.html_<unique_ids_and_timestamp>.php`
so if your file is called `template_views_farms_add.html_1234567_123456789_123.php` you can find the file you want to edit in app/views/farms/add.html.php

As hakre said: do not edit files in /tmp/cache! You can delete them and lithium will generate them again.